# Concatenating group_by series into one on big data

Tags: dataframe, group-by, concatenation, pandas-groupby, bigdata

I am trying to concatenate big data for easier access. So far I am trying to do it on a small scale with dataframes and it works. However, when I do it on large amount of files (2000) process runs out of memory. So I thought about concating files after I do "group_by".

Here is my code so far:

```
for file in files:
    tempDf = pd.read_parquet(file, columns=['state', 'date', 'id'])
    df = pd.concat([df, tempDf], ignore_index=True)
#Making sure date is of date type
df['JobDate']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
groupedDf=df.groupby(['state', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='m')])['id'].nunique()
groupeDfFrames=groupedDf.to_frame()

groupeDfFrames.to_parquet('grouped_states_job_count_total.parquet')
```

I planned to changing it to something more like this:

```
for file in files:
    tempDf = pd.read_parquet(file, columns=['state', 'date', 'id'])
    tempDf['JobDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    groupedDf = tempDf.groupby(['state', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='m')])['id'].nunique()
    groupConcat = pd.concat([df, groupedDf], ignore_index=True)

groupeDfFrames = groupConcat.to_frame()
groupeDfFrames.to_parquet('grouped_states_job_count_total.parquet')
```

However, I cannot properly concatenate grouped files (also there is issue of some files storing data of first half of the month and the other half is in another file so they should add up).

How can I make it work? Or is that a wrong approach?

Comment: Sounds like you need to save your processed dataframes, before you run out of memory, to get through the 2000 files.  You could save each processed grouped df to a csv file, or to a database, for example.  Then iterate through the processed files / database to put everything together.

Comment: I cannot store anything (external server). Would there be another way to do it, and is that a common practice?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do what you are hoping to do without being able to store anything.  Once you get through all the processing, what would you do with the output?

Comment: @Hammurabi I would like to reuse it often for training models.

Comment: Also, how else could I concatenate them (months and states add up numbers based on that)?